# Edit .docs and .xlsx files saved in firebase storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have some templates saved in firebase storage (these templates contain some variables), I also have a database in realtime database, I need to use the data from the database to edit the variables in the templates and after this make the new documents with the variables already edited, they are downloaded to the user's computer automatically.

what I want is that when calling the generateDocuments() function, go to the documents that I have in firebase storage, edit the templates with the data of the selected row and download them

In this way I get the data and paint it in a table using React

```
function getData() {
       onValue(ref(getDatabase(), 'BD/'), (snapshot) => {
           const data = snapshot.val();
           let vectorAuxiliar = [];

           for (let i in data) {
               const menu = (
                   <Menu
                       items={[
                                                      
                             {label:(<a onClick={()=>{generateDocuments(data[i])}}>generate Documents</a>)},
                       ]}
                   />
               );

               if (i !== "LISTA_NOMBRE" && i !== "DESCRIPCIÓN") {
                   vectorAuxiliar.push({
                       key: i,
                       RESPONSABLE_DEL_REGISTRO: data[i].RESPONSABLE_DEL_REGISTRO,
                       CAJA_COMPENSACION_FLIAR: data[i].CAJA_COMPENSACION_FLIAR,
                       APRENDICES_TERMINADOS: [data[i].APRENDICES_TERMINADOS],
                       TIPO_IDENTIFICACON: data[i].TIPO_IDENTIFICACON,
                       CORREO_ELECTRONICO: data[i].CORREO_ELECTRONICO,
                       FECHA_DE_REGISTRO: data[i].FECHA_DE_REGISTRO,
                       N_IDENTIFICACION: data[i].N_IDENTIFICACION,
                       SEGUNDO_APELLIDO: data[i].SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
                       LUGAR_NACIMIENTO: data[i].LUGAR_NACIMIENTO,
                       ENTIDAD_BANCARIA: data[i].ENTIDAD_BANCARIA,
                       PRIMER_APELLIDO: data[i].PRIMER_APELLIDO,
                       FONDO_CESANTIAS: data[i].FONDO_CESANTIAS,
                       NIVEL_DE_RIESGO: data[i].NIVEL_DE_RIESGO,
                       SEGUNDO_NOMBRE: data[i].SEGUNDO_NOMBRE,
                       TALLA_DELANTAL: data[i].TALLA_DELANTAL,
                       TALLA_SUDADERA: data[i].TALLA_SUDADERA,
                       ENTREGADO_G_D: [data[i].ENTREGADO_G_D],
                       PRIMER_NOMBRE: data[i].PRIMER_NOMBRE,
                       TIPO_CONTRATO: data[i].TIPO_CONTRATO,
                       TALLA_ZAPATOS: data[i].TALLA_ZAPATOS,
                       FONDO_PENSION: data[i].FONDO_PENSION,
                       FECHA_ENTREGA: data[i].FECHA_ENTREGA,
                       F_NACIMIENTO: data[i].F_NACIMIENTO,
                       ES_DE_AFUERA: data[i].ES_DE_AFUERA,
                       ESTADO_CIVIL: data[i].ESTADO_CIVIL,
                       FECHA_ARCHVO: data[i].FECHA_ARCHVO,
                       TALLA_JEANS: data[i].TALLA_JEANS,
                       UNIVERSIDAD: data[i].UNIVERSIDAD,
                       TIPO_CUENTA: data[i].TIPO_CUENTA,
                       DIRECCION: data[i].DIRECCION,
                       BARRIOMUN: data[i].BARRIOMUN,
                       F_INGRESO: data[i].F_INGRESO,
                       EPS_SALUD: data[i].EPS_SALUD,
                       TELEFONO: data[i].TELEFONO,
                       TAGS: [data[i].DOCUMENTOS],
                       N_CUENTA: data[i].N_CUENTA,
                       F_RETIRO: data[i].F_RETIRO,
                       CELULAR: data[i].CELULAR,
                       N_HIJOS: data[i].N_HIJOS,
                       CARRERA: data[i].CARRERA,
                       SALARIO: data[i].SALARIO,
                       C_COSTO: data[i].C_COSTO,
                       CIUDAD: data[i].CIUDAD,
                       GENERO: data[i].GENERO,
                       CARGO: data[i].CARGO,
                       TURNO: data[i].TURNO,
                       ARL: data[i].ARL,
                       ID: data[i].ID,
                       acciones:
                           <Dropdown overlay={menu}>
                               <a onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
                                   <Space>
                                       ACCIONES
                                   </Space>
                               </a>
                           </Dropdown>
                   });
               };
           };
           setData(vectorAuxiliar);
       });
   };
```

Comment: This is an English-speaking forum. Please write everything in English, including the title.

Comment: One cannot directly "edit files in storage" and I wonder what this code even has to do with it? There's no `generateDocuments()` function either - and "I want" is not a question, but  a demand. Could imagine how this works, but "I don't want" to work for you. Template formats are `*.doct` and `*.xslt`. So far there is no single question, but this seem to be multiple questions.

Comment: In this code I get the data from the realtime database and I show it in a table, after that the user must select from the table the row of the table from which he wants to generate the documents I do not have this method implemented since I do not find one way to bring the templates from firebase storage and edit them, the doubt I have is how do I take those templates from firebase storage and edit them